# Looping exploded results

Tags: php, arrays, loops, explode

I have a string as `$artikel['basisstaffel']` that looks like this:

```
3-10:17;
11-20:14;
21-30:12;
31-4:10;
41-50:7,50;
51-60:6,50;
61-110:6;
```

I first want to explode each line on the `;` then every line on the `:`.

So I tried this:

```
$explodesemicolon = explode(";",$artikel['basisstaffel']);
foreach ($explodesemicolon as $line) {
    $formatandprice = explode(":", $line);
    foreach ($formatandprice[0] as $result) {
        echo $result;
    }
}
```

But this echoes nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: replace `$formatandprice[0]` with `$formatandprice` or `echo $formatandprice[0]` before loop

Comment: Does `$artikel['basisstaffel']` have newlines in it after each `;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont actually need the inner loop, once you explode on the `:` you know there will be 2 occurances in the resulting array.

```
$explodesemicolon = explode(";",$artikel['basisstaffel']);
foreach ($explodesemicolon as $line) {
    $formatandprice = explode(":", $line);

    // check explode did what we expect
    if ( count($formatandprice) == 2 ) {
        echo $formatandprice[0];   // format I assume
        echo $formatandprice[1];   // price I assume
    } else {
        // woops something went wrong
    }
}
```